# How to access a specific index in twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to get a specific value from my object. I only want to print the first element in it, so I tried to treat it as an array by accessing it on the arrays position.

I also tried using the twig attribute function

However I can't get it to work.

```
{% for b in dotabets %}    
    {% for t in b.teams %}
       You bet on: {{ t.name[0] }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried {{ t.name|first }} but it only returns the first letter of each item in the loop.

bet.orm.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\Bet:
type: entity
repositoryClass: AppBundle\Entity\Repository\BetRepository
table: bets
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    createdDatetime:
        type: datetime
        column: created_datetime
    betTime:
        type: datetime
        column: bet_time
    status:
        type: integer
        length: 2
    result:
        type: integer
        length: 2
        nullable: true
    homeOdds:
        type: decimal
        scale: 2
    awayOdds:
        type: decimal
        scale: 2
    closedDatetime:
        type: datetime
        column: closed_datetime
        nullable: true
manyToOne:
    game:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Game
manyToMany:
    teams:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Team
        joinTable:
            name: bets_teams
            joinColumns:
                bet_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                team_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
```

Controller

```
class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{
/**
 * @Route("/", name="index")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showMatchesAction()
{
    $betRepo = $this->getEM()->getRepository('AppBundle:Bet');
    $dotaBets = $betRepo->findDota2Matches();
    $csgoBets = $betRepo->findCsGoMatches();


    return [
        'dotaBets' => $dotaBets,
        'csgoBets' => $csgoBets,
    ];
}
```

Comment: And how is your array structure?

Comment: its a one-dimentional array, I'm using symfony2 and passed an entity object to the view

Comment: So why are do you have two nested for's?  Maybe you want b.teams[0].name?

Comment: hey thanks for answering, but I have tried those solutions. I have added additional code to paint a better picture. It was very late yesterday when I posted sorry

Answer (score 3):

To access the first object on an array in twig you can use the 'first' filter of twig itself:

See [the Twig documentation about first](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/first.html) for that.

Basically you'd do:

```
{{ b.teams|first }}
```

to access the first value of an array.

Your example won't work though, since `{{ name }}` is not defined anywhere as variable. If it is contained in team you'd rather go like that:

```
{{ b.teams[0].name }}
```

assuming you want the name of the first team in your collection, with index starting at 0

Comment: hey thanks for answering, but I have tried those solutions. I have added additional code to paint a better picture. It was very late yesterday when I posted sorry

Comment: I am not quite sure how this resolves via a join table. you could investigate via dump